# flutter checkboxlisttile not selected on tap

Tags: flutter, dart

I experience an issue with my `listtile` being selected and checkbox changing color on select. i've tried wrapping the card with gesturedetector and changing listtile to checkboxlisttile but nothing; I can neither select it, nor does it check on tap. Here's the code:

```
Unit? selectedUnit;
ListView.builder(
                                    itemCount: allUnits.length,
                                    shrinkWrap: true,
                                    physics:
                                        const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                      Unit unit = allUnits[index];
                                      bool isSelected = unit == selectedUnit;
                                      bool isOccupied = unit.isOccupied!;

                                      return Card(
                                        elevation: 5.0,
                                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                                        ),
                                        child: ListTile(
                                          onTap: () {
                                            if (!isOccupied) {
                                              setState(() {
                                                selectedUnit = unit;
                                              });
                                            }
                                          },
                                          leading: isOccupied
                                              ? const Icon(
                                                  Icons.check_box,
                                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                                )
                                              : isSelected
                                                  ? const Icon(
                                                      Icons.check_box,
                                                      color: EKodi.themeColor,
                                                    )
                                                  : const Icon(
                                                      Icons
                                                          .check_box_outline_blank_rounded,
                                                      color: Colors.grey,
                                                    ),
                                          title: isOccupied
                                              ? Text(unit.name!,
                                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                                      decoration: TextDecoration
                                                          .lineThrough))
                                              : Text(unit.name!),
                                          subtitle: Text(unit.isOccupied!
                                              ? "Occupied"
                                              : "Vacant"),
                                        ),
                                      );
```

On tap the `listtile` is not selected and the checkbox is not checked.

Comment: There seems to be a contradiction in your post. In your last sentence you state that "On tap the listtile is selected and the checkbox is checked.", i.e. what should happen, happens. However, in the first sentence "I can neither select it, nor does it check on tap". Can you please [edit] your post to clarify your problem?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.